# What permission do I need to use an SQL Server Table Valued Parameter (TVP) as a stored proc parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, permissions, table-valued-parameters

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I've created a TVP that I want to use as a parameter to a stored proc but I get a message saying that it can't be found or I don't have permission.

I can use the TVP in a script or in the body of the stored proc, but when I try to use it as a parameter I get the error.

Any thoughts?

**Edit:** For clarification, the error I'm getting is on the creation of the stored proc

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order for a caller to use a `PROC` with a table valued parameter, you'll need to (unintuitively) [grant execute permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on the `TVP` type to those calling the `PROC` i.e.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON TYPE::[schema].[MyTVP] to [SomeRole]
```

**Edit**

I believe I was able to replicate the issue, viz working from a minimal set of permissions granted to a user. The vital step is for the DBO or Schema Owner of your TVP to grant you the following access to it, in order to be able to use it in a `PROC` (without this access, I was able to declare a loose variable of the TVP type, but not use it in a PROC).

```
GRANT REFERENCES ON TYPE::[schema].[MyTVP] to YOURROLE -- Or User.
```

[Grant Reference here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965.aspx)
(Obviously you'll also need `CREATE PROCEDURE` permission, plus relevant access to any objects used in the PROC)

Consumers of the PROC will need to also have the `GRANT EXECUTE` permission on the Proc and on the Type as per the initial answer.

Comment: If I can use the TVP in the body of the stored proc, doesn't that mean that I already have EXECUTE?

Comment: According to your link it seems like I did already have execute permission: `To declare a table variable that uses a user-defined table type, EXECUTE permission is required on that user-defined table type.`

Comment: Correct, it's on the creation of the stored proc

Comment: @JoshRusso I believe your DBO may need to grant you `GRANT REFERENCES ON TYPE::schema.tabletype` in order to be able to use it in a `PROC`.

Comment: The Grant References did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your table valued funtion that you want to grant access. Take the properties from the context menu.

1) Click on "Permissions" tab on the right.

2) Browse to the user name (SQL or Windows).

3) Select that user.

4) Under Explicit Permissions section at the bottom select Grant for Control   Permissions click OK.

5) click OK

[image]

Comment: Your Screenshot instruction #4 doesn't match the picture.